# getting same results from size command with different files ( C memory layout )

Tags: c, memory-layout

I'm learning about memory layout in C, I used the `size` command on a file compiled using gcc from the following C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

I got this result
[image]

Did the same but added an uninitialized int before the main function

```
int x;
int main ...
```

the output of the `size` command is the same

I understand that uninitialized variables goes to bss section in memory, so it's supposed to give me a different bss size with the second code ( 8 + 4 = 12 bytes )
so why the results are the same?

and what is initially stored in the data and bss sections ( their initial size is respectively 512 and 8 bytes)  ?

Comment: The `x` variable could be optimized out as unused.

Comment: To check what is there, you can use `readelf` or `objdump` on the binary. E.g. `readelf -W -a mem` or `objdump -t mem`

Comment: How did you compile your code? Using which command?

Comment: @Zakk I did ```gcc mem.c -o mem```

Comment: @numzero i'm not rally sure how to read the output of these commands, i'll look it up, thank you

Comment: @numzero I added ```printf("%d\n" , x);``` to the main function and I got a different text and data size, but the bss is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C compilers generally optimise their code unless you tell them not to.

As a rule of thumb, any function or variable you create but don't subsequently reference will be optimised out. In this case, your `int x;` was never subsequently referenced, so the compiler simply ignored it.

If, for example, you'd used `return x;` as the final statement in your `main()` function, that would then have referenced `x`. The compiler would then be obliged to allocate space in `.bss` for it, since you had not explicitly assigned a value and it was not declared `static`*.

Bear in mind, though, that `.bss` items are essentially virtual in nature. They've been declared but not instantiated. In other words, the accounting's been done, and at execute time space will finally be assigned in memory, but they won't occupy physical space in the executable.

One word of caution: the `.bss` segment is commonly zeroed at execute time, *but this is not guaranteed behaviour*, and you should not rely upon it. In other words, your `x` may vary!

---

*(* If you had assigned a non-zero value, that would put it in the `.data` segment. If you had assigned a zero value, or declared it static without an initialiser, it would be put in a segment that would be guaranteed zeroed at execute time, or in `.data`.)*